# React does not recognize the `accessibilityState` prop on a DOM element

Tags: react-native

enter code hereHello the developers of react-native, I wanted to integrate createMarterialTabBottom in my native project, I followed all the conventions, the views function but I always have a mistake in my console, please help me to solve this problem.

this is the code of my View App

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      activeColor="#fff"
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SettingsScreen"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) =>(
  <View><Text>Hello Home</Text></View>
);
const SettingsScreen = ({navigation}) =>(
  <View><Text>Hello seting</Text></View>
);
```

this the error of my console

```
[Warning: React does not recognize the `accessibilityState` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `accessibilitystate` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in a (created by Text)
    in Text (created by Link)
    in Link (created by BottomNavigation)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by BottomNavigation)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent (created by BottomNavigation)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent (created by Surface)
    in Surface (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(Surface))
    in withTheme(Surface) (created by BottomNavigation)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by BottomNavigation)
    in BottomNavigation (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(BottomNavigation))
    in withTheme(BottomNavigation) (created by MaterialBottomTabViewInner)
    in MaterialBottomTabViewInner (created by MaterialBottomTabView)
    in MaterialBottomTabView (created by MaterialBottomTabNavigator)
    in MaterialBottomTabNavigator (at App.js:12)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer))
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (created by ForwardRef(NavigationContainer))
    in ThemeProvider (created by ForwardRef(NavigationContainer))
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:11)
    in App (created by ExpoRootComponent)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (at NativeAppearance.web.tsx:51)
    in NativeAppearanceProvider (at src/index.tsx:70)
    in AppearanceProvider (created by ExpoRootComponent)
    in ExpoRootComponent (created by RootComponent)
    in RootComponent
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer][1]
```

Comment: I have the same issue, if someone knows the culprit, it could be a good idea to create a GitHub issue on the relevant repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also having this same issue, I found out that this warning was only generated when you compile the app in web, I tried compiling on an actual android device and the warning went away.